# How to remove padding or space in between the ui-block when using ui-grid in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-ui, css, jquery-mobile

Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/Cbde2/ and here are the results http://jsfiddle.net/Cbde2/embedded/result/

What I want is

> Bloack A, Block B, Block C

with no space or once char space in between.  I am using **jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css**
I am sure there will be a solution based on modifying the css for ui-block or ui-grid but I am not very good in css and not able to come up with a solution so far.. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this style in your  jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css

```
.ui-grid-b .ui-block-a, .ui-grid-b .ui-block-b, .ui-grid-b .ui-block-c {
    width: 11.333%;
    }
```